# Accessing URLs on same machine timing out

Tags: php, curl, ubuntu-16.04

At some point in the last week, one of our servers stopped being able to "talk to itself", so to speak.

We have a cronjob which calls a script via cURL at https://example.com/scripts/curl-script.php - example.com is hosted on the same machine - this no longer works. When run via the command line, you can see cURL looking up the correct external IP for the domain, but the connection simply times out. Same for another URL hosted on the same machine.

wget, or telnetting to example.com on ports 80 or 443, the same thing. Ping also times out (expected, as there's a firewall in place here) and so does traceroute (all hops are just * * *)

If I add an entry in `/etc/hosts` to map `example.com` to `127.0.0.1`, the script starts working as expected - it just can't talk to itself via it's external IP any more.

I haven't changed anything on this server for a while and I don't believe any automated updates have updated any of the related components. This has been working fine for weeks and I can't understand why it would suddenly stop.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a proper fix for this issue instead of the hosts file amendment?

Comment: Are there other scripts running and do they use and share a session? Perhaps the session is being blocked by a long-running script.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything causing the timeout. The website works absolutely perfectly when accessed from outside the box, and wouldn't timing out also block the requests when made via 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Sessions only block when you try to open the same session multiple times, so requests from the same browser / server would do that. Using a different ip address or accessing from a browser would simply start / use another session.

Comment: Hm, fair point. I'll see what I can figure out. Is there a command I can use to test for a script / process that's been running that sort of time?

Comment: There are, but I'm not that familiar with them. At least `ps` should show you how long certain processes are running and there are other tools to check for open files.